# Why isn't humanoid health changing?

Tags: roblox

So I am making a script to heal a player by an amount however the health isn't changing at all. I know the code is executing because I can see the output by the print statement, however the print statement always reads 100 for some reason. I have tried disabling the health regeneration script but it seems that that did not work either.

(In a script in a tool)

```
local Medkit = script.Parent

Medkit.RemoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function()
    local Player = Medkit.Parent
    print(Player.Humanoid.Health)
    if Player.Humanoid.Health <= Player.Humanoid.MaxHealth - 50 then --Change the number to the healing power mentioned below
        Player.Humanoid.Health = Player.Humanoid.Health + 50 --This number determines the healing power
    else
        Player.Humanoid.Health = Player.Humanoid.MaxHealth
    end
end)
```

(Dont judge my script, im relatively new)

EDIT: I tried `Humanoid:TakeDamage()` set to a negative value but that didn't work. It bugged out the health system and set it to values over the MaxHealth.

EDIT2: I have included some print statements in my logic.
I have included print statements in the logic as you asked.

```
local Medkit = script.Parent

Medkit.RemoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function()
    local Player = Medkit.Parent
    print(Player.Humanoid.Health)
    if Player.Humanoid.Health <= Player.Humanoid.MaxHealth - 50 then --Change the number to the healing power mentioned below
        Player.Humanoid.Health = Player.Humanoid.Health + 50 --This number determines the healing power
        print("added 50")
    else
        Player.Humanoid.Health = Player.Humanoid.MaxHealth
        print("set 50")
    end
end)
```

The way I tested this script is by manually setting the `Player.Humanoid.Health` by the explorer to values. I have tested ```Player. Humanoid.Health```` = 60, 50, 40, and 30, but all have yielded the same output;

```
100
set 50
```

Even if `Player.Humanoid.Health` somehow read 100, it would still set the value to 100.

EDIT3: I have tested a different value for `Player.Humanoid.MaxHealth`, it being `150`, therefore `Player.Humanoid.Health` being `150` as well. However, the code still printed:

```
100
set 50
```

EDIT4:The same thing mentioned in EDIT3 happened when printing `Player.Humanoid.MaxHealth`.

Comment: What value is `Player.Humanoid.MaxHealth`. I suggest you put some prints inside your if logic also

Comment: ```Player.Humanoid.MaxHealth = 100```

Comment: What makes you think `Player.Humanoid.Health` isn't actually 100? From what you've described, `Health` is 100 and `MaxHealth` is 100, so this script just runs `Player.Humanoid.Health = Player.Humanoid.MaxHealth` every time. Insert some print statements to verify. So basically if the health is anywhere between 50 and 100, it'll jump straight back to 100. If it's below 50, it'll have 50 added, again jumping straight back to 100

Comment: I edited my question for you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out why.

It wasn't the tool that was broken, it was the method I used to test it. I tested it locally, and since `filtering = enabled`, it didn't update it on the server, therefore the health didn't change.

Thank you all for helping anyway, you led me to the right path for figuring this out.